# Dynamic ServiceNow Reports connected to SQL Server Data Source

Tags: sql-server, servicenow

I have a requirement to create Reports on Service Now that refer directly to a data source on SQL Server Database. I want to know how can I achieve this.

I say dynamically, to be assured of getting right data in time that refers to the data on the database.

I am new to servicenow, could someone please help me.

Comment: I could find a way. Have blogged the same here: https://medium.com/@cadarsh88/servicenow-reporting-with-sql-server-database-f71953029e76